# Subtract two value by difference criteria in same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In this table we see different transaction in same date some of Transaction Dr and some transaction Cr. I need Cr - Dr as Transaction Amount per date.
Please see screenshot [1st Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GG1w.png)

[image]

Result will be-
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxnci.png)

[image]

Comment: Please see: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Don't use images. Copy/Paste the values here or even better, provide us with the code to make the tables and values.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a case when and group by

```
select date, sum(case when drcr = 'CR' then amount 
                  when drcr = 'DR' then -amount 
                    else 0 end)
from my_table 
group by date
```

Comment: you forgot the sum

Comment: thanks for useful comment  .. sum added and typo removed

Comment: @anonyXmous   correct  ..  a your question  .. upvoted

Comment: Life would be tragic if it weren't funny - SH

Comment: ... really true ..  luckily there are fun things

Answer (score 0):

as @scaisEdge but you need a sum.

```
select date, sum(case when drcr = 'CR' then amuont else (-1 * amount) end) as tran_amt
from my_table 
group by date
```

This should be clear, but the way it works is to add credits and substract debits to the total for each date.

Comment: Create the data, run / test it and you will see aumont in there.

Comment: we should share the bounty as well. haha

Comment: I don't like this part: "-1 * amount" since it is an extra computation but still works.

Comment: @anonyXmous -- I doubt it -- remember this is compiled. I expect prefixing a numeric amount with `"-"` (if it works on a given platform) translates to `"-1 *"` -- I think my code is a little clearer. But I'm not married to it -- as evidenced by my upvote to scaisEdge answer.